# Spring MVC binding a formatted phone number to a non-formatted field in the database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a phone number in a hibernate domain object

```
String phoneNumber;
```

I have the domain object bound to a field using spring forms

```
<sf:input path="myobject.phoneNumber" />
```

The trouble is that I also have a jQuery Mask plugin that forces the user to enter the field in the following number format

```
(##) #### ####
```

When I receive the field on the server side it is formatted as above, however, I want to store it without the formatting so that other formats can be used in the future.  In the database it will look like.

```
##########
```

I suppose some sort of Property Editor would work but I don't know how it would work because I would be converting from `<String,String>` and there are other fields bound to Strings in the form.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: write the implementation in getPhoneNumber().
Hibernate uses getter and setters to assgin/read the data from the domain objects.

Comment: I did think of that but that would force the use of the format throughout the entire application.  In addition the JQuery mask library expects the correct format when binding, so it expects the format `(##) #### ####`, also I am not sure how that would affect the hibernate update/save, wouldn't it expect it to be ########## on the getter?

Comment: I think the most versatile option would be to have PhoneNumber as a class. Then you can easily cConvert from String to PhoneNumber. You could also use multiple formats with that.

Comment: @Bhashit-Parikh, So if I make a simple `PhoneNumber` class and replace the String value for this new object, how will I map this to hibernate or will it automatically use the `toString()` method of the `PhoneNumber` class when getting the value and saving to the DB?

Comment: You could mark the PhoneNumber class with the `@Embeddable` annotation. Lookup `@Embedded` also. Hibernate will take care of the mapping.  You can map the properties of the PhoneNumber class like normal entity classes.